# Enumerative Geometry - General equation of the transversal line intersecting 3 skew lines in 3D

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, geometry

How can I find the general equation of the line that intersects the 3 skew lines? I know that this general equation will represent a ruled surface of one sheet, specifically a hyperboloid.

{X=-2t+2     Y=3t      Z=2t

{X=-3t Y=-2t+2 Z=2t

{X=2t+2 Y=-3t Z=2t

I used GeoGebra to create these 3 parametric equations I know them to be skew pairwise. I now want to find the general equation that will represent my Hyperboloid.

I assume the answer should resemble the general form of the hyperboloid.

Comment: Do you mean that the hyperboloid contains all three lines?

Comment: No, @QuarterLemon, every line on the quadric surface intersects all three lines.

Answer (score 2):

**Sketch**: Call the respective lines $\ell_1$, $\ell_2$, and $\ell_3$. For each point $P\in\ell_1$, consider the plane $\Pi_P$ determined by $P$ and $\ell_2$. The line $\ell_3$ will (generically) meet $\Pi_P$ in a unique point $Q_P$. [You will, of course, want to use different variables as parameters for $\ell_2$ and $\ell_3$.] The locus of the lines $\overleftrightarrow{PQ_P}$ (as $P$ varies over $\ell_1$) will be your ruled surface.

Note that you can get everything explicitly parametrically here, using $t$ to parametrize $\ell_1$—and hence the pencil of lines $\overleftrightarrow {PQ_P}$—and $s$ as the parameter along those lines.

**Comment**: If you want an example where things work out rather nicely, take instead the lines
\begin{align*}
\ell_1: \quad & x=t, \ y=z=0  \\
\ell_2: \quad & x=t+1,\ y=1,\  z=t \\
\ell_3: \quad & x=t+1,\  y=2,\  z=2t+2 
\end{align*}